# Its possible put a break line after grep?

Tags: linux, unix, shellcode

I have the code like this:

```
 scan-codes | grep -i '[!]\| url:\|started\|Aborted' | grep -v 'Effective\|style\|WARNING\|The version'
```

Output:

```
        [+] Started: Sat Feb 19 05:21:00 2022
             | [!] 1 vulnerability identified:
             | [!] Title: Cookie Notice & Compliance for GDPR / CCPA < 2.1.2 - Admin+ Stored Cross-Site Scripting
    ############## need break line here ##############
             | [!] 1 vulnerability identified:
             | [!] Title: WPBakery Page Builder < 6.4.1 - Authenticated Stored Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)
############## need break line here ##############
            WARNING: Nokogiri was built against libxml version 2.9.10, but has dynamically loaded 2.9.12
```

And i want to put a break line (like \n) after grep.
Its a scan, so i cant change the file.

Comment: That command line doesn't work. There is a superfluous `")`at the end.

Comment: Also, how do you get the last line starting with `WARNING`?. The first grep does not select it, and the second grep does not output it due to the `-v`. Please provide a sample input.

Comment: @phunsoft i mistake when i paste

Comment: My second comment still holds true: There should not be a line with "WARNING" in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to use single `awk` script:

If matching combined 2 `grep` conditions than print current line + newline every 2nd line:

```
  awk '/\[!\]| url:|started|Aborted/ && !/Effective|style|WARNING|The version/ {ln++; print $0 (ln % 2) ? "\n": "";}'
```

#### Explanation

`/\[!\]| url:|started|Aborted/`          Positive line matching condition
`!/Effective|style|WARNING|The version/` Negative line matching condition

```
{ # For each line passing all conditions
   ln++; # count printed line
   newLineMaker = (ln % 2) ? "\n": ""; # New line marker any 2nd line
   print $0 newLineMaker; # print 
}
```

Comment: This inserts an additional newline after **each** matching line. The OP wanted one after - what is still not clear - "each grep". The desired output as shown has one after every second matching line.